# What is the difference between .ini and .conf?

Tags: filenames

As mentioned, what is the difference? or is there any concern to use them?

Answer (score 19):

Unlike DOS-based OSes, in Unix and Linux file extensions are mostly meaningless outside of human-readable reasons. [INI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INI_file) is a configuration file standard.

A .conf file could be an INI file, or it could be any other configuration system that the application supports. MySQL, for example, uses the file `my.cnf` by default for configuration, which is an INI file.

Comment: Are .ini files carry overs from Windows coders?

Comment: @Rob Kindof, but not really.  It is like many programs will use an extension that defines the format (openbox's `.xml` config for example).  There isn't really a solid convention.  Personally I put the filetype as an extension if I use one (which I usually don't).

Answer (score 7):

**INI**-style configuration files may have a format similar to this:

```
[heading1]
key1=value
key2=value

[heading2]
a=1
b=2

etc...
```

**conf**-style configuration files are more varied. They may look similar to this:

```
# A comment
button 1 {
  name "hello"
  "text" hi.there
  "more..." {
    "something 123"  bla.bla "123"
  }
}

# Another comment
button 2 {
  # hello
  x=2
}
```

Or perhaps a bit like this:

```
# set server port
server.port = 1234

# make everything go faster
machine.turbo_button = activated
```

On Mac, Linux and BSD, configuration files of all styles usually have UNIX-style line endings, while it may be a bit more varied on Windows. `.ini` files on Windows usually have DOS/Windows-style line endings.

Comment: There is nothing about the INI standard that says that ini files need DOS line endings. My php.ini file doesn't have them.

Comment: do you have an example of such a UNIX application that expects its line endings to be DOS-style?

Comment: This is pretty much my understanding, too.

Comment: Btw, dos line endings are `\r\n`, `0xD 0xA` (decimal 13 and 10, not hex).

Comment: and the line endings have nothing to do with the file format, it's just a normal text file with the usual system line endings. Most INI files use dos line endings because most INI files are on windows machines.

Comment: @jordanm Check out `man mke2fs.conf`. This is the configuration file for `mke2fs` which creates ext2/ext3/ext4 filesystem, located at /etc/mke2fs.conf on my machine with a INI-style formatting.

Comment: @jordanm Yes, if you have Steam installed, several of the games may have ini-files with CRLF endings, like ie. `.config/deadbolt_game/prefs.ini`. Also, Google Cloud SDK comes with `pyparsing` which includes `karthik.ini` with CRLF. These exists on my system, but they are arguably not needed by "real" UNIX applications.

Comment: @Alexander those are applications that didn't exist on *nix in 2012 when I made that comment and the original version of this answer was a little different. I believe I was being pedantic about the term "usually" originally used.